# How to get Quota limit from Google Analytics using C#

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I have developed the application which download the data from GA and now I am facing the issue `dailyLimitExceeded`

I just want to know how can we know how many Quota is reamining using C#

is there any property in `ManagementResource.ProfilesResource.ListRequest req;` which can return the remaining quota.

Comment: That information is unavailable, you have to check the dev console manually to see if you are getting close to your quota.

Comment: The limit is 10k requests per profile, and a total of 50k request over all.  Which limit are you hitting. You can request that the 50k quota be extended

Comment: I know that but I just want to know how many request is remaining.

Comment: you have to check the website manually there is no way to get that information programmatically at this time.